# Will i get a notification if supervised user power wash my chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Chromebook that my little brothers use as supervised users. I am away, if they were to power wash it would i be able to know about it without going home and looking on it? Does it send you a message or does the activity stop or what happens?

Answer (score 2):

So far as consumer Chromebooks go, in general, [anyone can powerwash](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/C0Q_OgYd3eE;context-place=topicsearchin/chromebook-central/authorid$3AAPn2wQed7VDJZoQoNemIw3mNWM4GVK1Kr-1UyxjKhD8sVvCz2mcXNQVKwJ6z5tgXldq3t8RLmtDH%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) them and you [won't get any notification](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/hBpTt8iul6w).

Comment: so will there be any obvious signs that it was power washed. Like if i go to the site to check the history, will it tell me the accounts gone?

Comment: Do i have to see it in person to know or will i be able to tell from the site or anything.